# Communication between Python and WCF

Tags: python, wcf, notifications, pooling

I have multiples servers (200-300) in Python 2.4 calling a WCF service using REST. I would like to be able to notify those servers of some changes that occured on the WCF service instead of asking all servers in Python to do some pooling to detect such changes.

How can I do such broadcast, notification to avoid the pooling?

Thanks
Sylvain

Comment: You may want to go with a message based solution. Are all of the servers behind the same firewall or connected through some VPN?

Comment: Thanks
Yes, all those servers are behing the same firewall. All servers are into the same internal network.
I never had the chance to work with a message based solution. Are you refering to msmq?

Comment: MSMQ or any other message queue should work. Look at the service bus pattern and that will give you an idea of what I was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

A message bus seems to be the right choice. You might want to have a look at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org). It's cross-platform and has bindings in a variety of languages.